# Virtualbox: EIZO’s "Screen InStyle" software in Windows 10 Guest (Linux Host)?

Tags: virtualbox, display, external-display

Would [EIZO’s "Screen InStyle"](https://www.eizoglobal.com/products/flexscan/screen-instyle/) software also fully work and function from within a Windows 10 (Virtualbox) Guest, with a Linux Host, for a USB-C connected monitor, like, for instance, [this one](https://www.eizoglobal.com/products/flexscan/ev3285/index.html) ?

*<sub>Meta question: Can this question be answered at all a priori, with sufficient knowledge of Virtualbox (and EIZO's software/hardware) - or only empirically by trying it out ?</sub>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works :-)

..........................

Comment: Meta question: did you somehow deduce or compute this answer a priori,  or did you try it?

Comment: Tried it empirically.